# Installing CAT6 in a wall without using trunking or conduit

Tags: walls, data-wiring, cabling

I’ve just bought an old house in the UK (circa 1902) and am running CAT6 cable through most of it. I bought [Outdoor Cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01GK898I0/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1) as I needed something a bit more durable. The downside is that I can’t run any trunking or conduit as the cable itself is quite wide and I’m running 4 cables to a box through most of the house.

My question is, apart from not being able to easily replace the cable further down the line, are there any major problems to chasing in outdoor CAT6 cable and just plastering over it?

Comment: How are the walls constructed?

Comment: Brick with plaster over.